# Is there any way to view the physical SQLs executed by Calcite JDBC?

Tags: jdbc, apache-calcite

Recently I am studying Apache Calcite, by now I can use `explain plan for` via JDBC to view the logical plan, and I am wondering how can I view the physical sql in the plan execution? Since there may be bugs in the physical sql generation so I need to make sure the correctness.

```scala
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:")
    val calciteConnection = connection.asInstanceOf[CalciteConnection]
    val rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema()

    val dsInsightUser = JdbcSchema.dataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:13306/insight?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "insight_admin","xxxxxx")
    val dsPerm = JdbcSchema.dataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:13307/permission?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "perm_admin", "xxxxxx")

    rootSchema.add("insight_user", JdbcSchema.create(rootSchema, "insight_user", dsInsightUser, null, null))
    rootSchema.add("perm", JdbcSchema.create(rootSchema, "perm", dsPerm, null, null))

    val stmt = connection.createStatement()
    val rs = stmt.executeQuery("""explain plan for select "perm"."user_table".* from "perm"."user_table" join "insight_user"."user_tab" on "perm"."user_table"."id"="insight_user"."user_tab"."id" """)
    val metaData = rs.getMetaData()

    while(rs.next()) {
      for(i <- 1 to metaData.getColumnCount) printf("%s ", rs.getObject(i))
      println()
    }
```

result is

```
EnumerableCalc(expr#0..3=[{inputs}], proj#0..2=[{exprs}])
  EnumerableHashJoin(condition=[=($0, $3)], joinType=[inner])
    JdbcToEnumerableConverter
      JdbcTableScan(table=[[perm, user_table]])
    JdbcToEnumerableConverter
      JdbcProject(id=[$0])
        JdbcTableScan(table=[[insight_user, user_tab]])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Calcite Hook, `Hook.QUERY_PLAN` that is triggered with the JDBC query strings.  From the [source](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/ec9231ad6c5a8764a17f5791a676951a90337015/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/runtime/Hook.java#L89-L92):

```
/** Called with a query that has been generated to send to a back-end system.
* The query might be a SQL string (for the JDBC adapter), a list of Mongo
* pipeline expressions (for the MongoDB adapter), et cetera. */
QUERY_PLAN;
```

You can register a listener to log any query strings, like this in Java:

```
Hook.QUERY_PLAN.add((Consumer<String>) s -> LOG.info("Query sent over JDBC:\n" + s));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to see the generated SQL query by setting `calcite.debug=true` system property. The exact place where this is happening is in [JdbcToEnumerableConverter](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/6ea2fd03cbc366b673ac0adfcd246b2e3e7321dc/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/adapter/jdbc/JdbcToEnumerableConverter.java#L98). As this is happening during the execution of the query you will have to remove the `"explain plan for"`
from `stmt.executeQuery`.

Note that by setting debug mode to true you will get a lot of other messages as well as other information regarding generated code.